# How to spilt tabs jquery file with codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi all I am a new of codeigniter I have stuck it a few day I a have problam with my jquery tab I can not split it I try to search google and youtube but I can not do it who can help me please Example My jquery Tab:

```
 <div id="demopage">
        <div class="container1">
            <ul class="rtabs">
                <li><a href="#menu">menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
<div class="panel-container">
 <div id="menu">
 <p>menu</p>
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
 <p>contact</p>
</div>

<div id="about">
<p>about</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and I try to edit in view and controller:

```
View
 <div id="demopage">
        <div class="container1">
            <ul class="rtabs">
                <li><a href="#<?php echo base_url().'./site/menu' ?>">menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#<?php echo base_url().'./site/contact' ?>">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#<?php echo base_url().'./site/menu' ?>">About</a></li>
            </ul>
<div class="panel-container">
 <div id="menu">
 <p>menu</p>
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
 <p>contact</p>
</div>

<div id="about">
<p>about</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
function menu(){
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('menu');
$this->load->view('footer');


function contact(){
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('contact');
$this->load->view('footer');


function about(){
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('about');
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope header and footer will be same for all, If so,

```
function your_function_name(){
    $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('menu',"",true);
    $data['contact'] = $this->load->view('contact',"",true);
    $data['about'] = $this->load->view('about',"",true);
   $this->load->view("your_view_file",$data);
}
```

Third parameter to view, will get the view in to a variable instead of loading it to the view. So collect all views and echo in main view file.

in view

```
<div class="panel-container">
      <div id="menu">
            <p><?php echo $menu ?></p>
       </div>
       <div id="contact">
           <p><?php echo $contact ?></p>
      </div>
      <div id="about">
           <p><?php echo $about ?></p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok brother I will test ur code but now I am have lunch 20mn very thz q

Comment: Sure, test it.. get back with result.

Comment: This time maby the end of me :( i canot do

Comment: I put ur code the error said undefine varible result. it meas varible result my query in controller

Comment: Hi brother do u have other way for me

Comment: If I don't split jquery tab .when I query multi database the erro said undefine varible

Comment: if I change jquery tab to css tab I think I will can  continue this project . but its washing my time

Comment: ya ok... tel me what is the error, we will fixt hat.

Comment: ur code its ok but now I have problam with my two query in 1page the error said undefine varible :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93345/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-user307709).

Comment: Hi brother could u help me ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361635/how-to-show-pagination-with-product-category-codeigniter?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: last night I cahng the code it work but hav problam with pagination brother

Comment: could u help me brother ?

Comment: what issue ur grtting there?/

Comment: I can not link and limit content

Comment: Yes I folowing document

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93345/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-user307709

Comment: hi brother are u free ?  can I ask u 1 about jquery ?

Comment: Hi brother are u free could u help me only one more If I fail this project They wil pass me false job  and I will no have job .could u help me only one more. about pagintion get by category

Comment: waht is hangout brother

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1) You need to include respective jQuery files.

2) Change your `<li>` 's `href` attribute to proper tab.

3) In your case, remove `<?php echo base_url()?>`.

4) The correct syntax should be: `<li><a href="#menu' ?>">menu</a></li>`

**Explanation:**

jQuery tabs work as following:

1) First create a `<ul>` for tab headers.

2) For each `<li>`, a named anchor to content with `href=#id-of-the-content`.

3) By clicking on a `<li>`, only respective content will show, others will hide.