# How to show pagination with product category codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Hi all I am a new of codeigniter I have problam with pagination on codeigniter I try to search google and youtube but I can not do it who can help me please 
this my code model:

```
<?php
class Product_model extends CI_Model {


    function get_product($category="") {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }


    function get_total($category="") {
        $this->db->select('count(*) AS num_row');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row()->num_row;
    }

}
```

and this my controoler code:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product_model','product');
    }
public function menu()
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['burger'] = $this->product->get_product('burger');
        $total_burger = $this->product->get_total('burger');
        $limit_burger = 1;
        $link_burger = 'http://localhost/mbl/site/menu/burger';
        $data['pagination_burger'] = $this->pagination($total_burger,$limit_burger,$link_burger);

        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('nav_view');
        $this->load->view('content_view');
        $this->load->view('content_left_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('content_right_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }



    private function pagination($total ,$per_page ,$link) {

        $config['base_url'] = $link;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
```

and my view:

```
<h1>Burger</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($burger as $val) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $val->title; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php echo $pagination_burger; ?>
```

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: I read .but u can edit my code ?

Answer (score 0):

In Codigniter it is very simple

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
```

load this library

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

or

[check this url](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/pagination.html)